# Display Nodes at the same depth not working

Tags: java, for-loop, queue, binary-search-tree, nodes

Example of what Binary Search Tree looks like with OPTIMAL inserted:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrhxx.png

```
void wordsAtDepth() {
        int depth = 0;
        int numOfNodes;
        Queue queue = new Queue(32); // Make a new Queue called queue.
        queue.insert(root); // Insert the root into the queue

        // While queue is not empty we will continue the while loop
        while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            // numOfNodes keeps track of how many times we are going to 
            // continue the for loop in the current while loop.
            numOfNodes = (int) Math.pow(2, depth);
            // for loop will continue until i is equal to or is greater 
            // than numOfNodes.
            for (int i = 0; i < numOfNodes; i++) {
                // Current will equal to the removed element from the 
                // queue.
                Node Current = queue.remove();
                // If Current does not equal null then print current 
                //  and insert its' left and right child.
                // If Current does equal null then do nothing go to the 
                //  next iteration of the for loop
                if(Current != null){
                    System.out.print(Current.cData);
                    queue.insert(Current.leftChild);
                    queue.insert(Current.rightChild);
                }
            }
            // Makes new line every time we finish the while loop. 
            // Which means new line for the next iteration of the
            // while loop to separate the different depths.
            System.out.println(" ");
            depth++;
        }
    }
```

Nodes contain char values. For the word OPTIMAl it prints correctly, but for words like HAPPY or SUPERMAN they print incorrectly. For example: SUPERMAN: S PU ER AMN SPUERAMNPUERAMN ERAMNAMNNEMNNAMNN AMNNNNAMNNNNNNNN NNNNNNNN

Instead of using **numOfNodes = (int) Math.pow(2, depth);** the code works when I use the **numOfNodes = queue.length()**. But I WANT to use **numOfNodes = (int) Math.pow(2, depth);** since the for loop will should loop for the ammount of Nodes at a depth. Since the number of Nodes in a depth is 2^Depth.

Comment: It is not clear what your data is, as the function takes no arguments, and unknown variables/attributes pop up. It is not clear how a word like "SUPERMAN" is represented in your tree. Also, what is the expected output for SUPERMAN?

Answer (score 0):

If you expect the number of nodes at a certain depth to be that power of 2, then you must make sure to deal with the case where your tree is not *perfect*, because then -- even if your tree is *complete* -- the bottom level will not be fully filled.

The simple fix seems to be that you **always** add 2 entries to the queue for every entry you pop from it. So change this:

```
                if(Current != null){
                    System.out.print(Current.cData);
                    queue.insert(Current.leftChild);
                    queue.insert(Current.rightChild);
                }
```

to this:

```
                if(Current != null){
                    System.out.print(Current.cData);
                    queue.insert(Current.leftChild);
                    queue.insert(Current.rightChild);
                } else {
                    queue.insert(null);
                    queue.insert(null);
                }
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It does print out words like SUPERMAN correctly, but it seems I have run into a problem with the method call making a bunch of additional lines, and doesn't stop. I know that new lines are being made by System.out.println(" "); at the end of the while loop. I assume I don't have an effective way of breaking out of the while loop(I am not sure).